# open('output1.txt', 'w').write("Hello guys") versus openvar.write("Hello guys")

Tags: python, file, variables

When I do

```
open('output1.txt', 'w').write("Hello guys")
```

A file called output1.txt is immediatly created and contains the string "Hello guys".
But when I do

```
openvar = open('output2.txt', 'w')
openvar.write("Hello guys")
```

Then only the file output2.txt is created. The text "Hello guys" will only be seen on the output2.txt when I do `openvar.close()`.
Why is this behaviour different only because of an extra variable assignment?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python detects that the file object is not referenced anymore in your first case so the garbage collector will collect it and call its destructor which closes the file.

In the second case the file object still exists so it's not closed automatically.

---

You should **always** close your files when you area done. The `with` statement makes this pretty easy:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('Hello')
```

As soon as the block is left, the file is closed again - even if the code inside the block raises an exception.

---

If you need to keep the file open for some reason (e.g. because you are going to write more data), you can `.flush()` it to force the system to empty the write buffer and actually writes it to the file.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case garbage collector will close file for you. There are no references to that file. In the second case you have created a reference to the file. You have to manualy close it, or it will be closed by garbage collector when reference is destroyed.